# Run multiple nodes on same Ganache blockchain

Tags: ganache

I am trying to run two nodes on the same ganache blockchain. I tried using the localhost link in the other node which was connected to the same network but it sort of had a mirroring effect. Any idea as to why this is happening and how can I run the same contract on two nodes?

Comment: Do you mean *nodes* when you say devices? Otherwise I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: Yes. I meant nodes.